# Curled fingers: Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I played imported animation, the character's fingers get curled and his mouth opened. I might be able to fix that by editing adjusting bones in unity. But with so many characters and each time dragging them from assets to scene.

It's a bit too much misery and it's slowed me down, I need this get done fast.

Unity Masters, PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: If this question doesn't involve any programming you should ask this on Unity answers and/or gamedev.stackexchange.com. Also provide more details about your character model and how you play the animation.

Comment: I take your advice. I'll go look there and hey there's no direct pic upload option I've cropped-pic ready to upload but where?

Answer (score 0):

the bones in your **imported model rig** must contain all the fingers and other parts bones that doesnt move correctly , if it does then **assign them to your avatar** as you are setting up your avatar (look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfiguringtheAvatar.html) for avatar setup) , after that if your animation animates fingers then your model will also

Comment: Thanks buddy, I doubled checked it before posting the question. The  character's rig and animation were from the same source.

Comment: All the bones are mapped correctly after you employ Enforce T-pose.  But muscles were being dirty. Tried all but couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So that's right you don't get timely help. AnyWays,

[SOLUTION]
The animations was imported from iClone 5. Now I was importing animation separately and then applying it to the .fbx character. So I alternatively imported the animations embedded with the character. Now this is helpful only in case the original character is also being imported from iClone. Then in the rigged configuration I reset the pose>Enforce T-pose>automap> again automap>enforce T-Pose. Worked for me.

[SOLUTION2]
I had alternative in which I could mask hand animations (not using them) and remove jaw from 3d exchange while exporting fbx. But they looked so lovely I had to look further.

Sometimes you can't find the solution, I guess you are the only solution then. That's how everybody learns. hopes it helps.